# c++ header file compiler issue (Sales_item.h) c++ primer example

Tags: c++

I recently bought c++ primer fifth edition and I've been trying to do the example projects using Sales_item.h and I've been facing some compiler issues with a specific line of code. Here's the whole header file:

```
/*
 * This file contains code from "C++ Primer, Fifth Edition", by Stanley B.
 * Lippman, Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo, and is covered under the
 * copyright and warranty notices given in that book:
 * 
 * "Copyright (c) 2013 by Objectwrite, Inc., Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo."
 * 
 * 
 * "The authors and publisher have taken care in the preparation of this book,
 * but make no expressed or implied warranty of any kind and assume no
 * responsibility for errors or omissions. No liability is assumed for
 * incidental or consequential damages in connection with or arising out of the
 * use of the information or programs contained herein."
 * 
 * Permission is granted for this code to be used for educational purposes in
 * association with the book, given proper citation if and when posted or
 * reproduced.Any commercial use of this code requires the explicit written
 * permission of the publisher, Addison-Wesley Professional, a division of
 * Pearson Education, Inc. Send your request for permission, stating clearly
 * what code you would like to use, and in what specific way, to the following
 * address: 
 * 
 *     Pearson Education, Inc.
 *     Rights and Permissions Department
 *     One Lake Street
 *     Upper Saddle River, NJ  07458
 *     Fax: (201) 236-3290
*/ 

/* This file defines the Sales_item class used in chapter 1.
 * The code used in this file will be explained in
 * Chapter 7 (Classes) and Chapter 14 (Overloaded Operators)
 * Readers shouldn't try to understand the code in this file
 * until they have read those chapters.
*/

#ifndef SALESITEM_H
// we're here only if SALESITEM_H has not yet been defined 
#define SALESITEM_H

// Definition of Sales_item class and related functions goes here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {
// these declarations are explained section 7.2.1, p. 270 
// and in chapter 14, pages 557, 558, 561
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool operator<(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool 
operator==(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
public:
    // constructors are explained in section 7.1.4, pages 262 - 265
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
    Sales_item() = default;
    Sales_item(const std::string &book): bookNo(book) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream &is) { is >> *this; }
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);

    // operations on Sales_item objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    double avg_price() const;
// private members as before
private:
    std::string bookNo;      // implicitly initialized to the empty string
    unsigned units_sold = 0; // explicitly initialized
    double revenue = 0.0;
};

// used in chapter 10
inline
bool compareIsbn(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs) 
{ return lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn(); }

// nonmember binary operator: must declare a parameter for each operand
Sales_item operator+(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);

inline bool 
operator==(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    // must be made a friend of Sales_item
    return lhs.units_sold == rhs.units_sold &&
           lhs.revenue == rhs.revenue &&
           lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn();
}

inline bool 
operator!=(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs); // != defined in terms of operator==
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item& Sales_item::operator+=(const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold; 
    revenue += rhs.revenue; 
    return *this;
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item 
operator+(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    Sales_item ret(lhs);  // copy (|lhs|) into a local object that we'll return
    ret += rhs;           // add in the contents of (|rhs|) 
    return ret;           // return (|ret|) by value
}

std::istream& 
operator>>(std::istream& in, Sales_item& s)
{
    double price;
    in >> s.bookNo >> s.units_sold >> price;
    // check that the inputs succeeded
    if (in)
        s.revenue = s.units_sold * price;
    else 
        s = Sales_item();  // input failed: reset object to default state
    return in;
}

std::ostream& 
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Sales_item& s)
{
    out << s.isbn() << " " << s.units_sold << " "
        << s.revenue << " " << s.avg_price();
    return out;
}

double Sales_item::avg_price() const
{
    if (units_sold) 
        return revenue/units_sold; 
    else 
        return 0;
}
#endif
```

And the line that I'm having an issue with on multiple compilers is this:
 Sales_item() = default;

I've tried this in both Visual studio and Dev c++.  Both are up to date for c++ 11.

Devc++ gives the compiler error that Sales_item was not found in the scope.
Visual studio gives the error that Sales_item() = default; is undefined.

Can anyone help me find what I'm missing?

Comment: update the post by Trimming down all the Unnecessary information . That helps to trace out the issue

Comment: Yes, in other words, post a [MCVE].

Comment: If your version of VS is older than 2013 it won't support defaulted functions.

Answer (score 1):

This looks and compiles OK for me. Are you sure you've turned on C++11 support in your compilers? It's often off by default (e.g. Clang has `-std=c++11`).

For Visual Studio, check C++11 feature support at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx.

Edit: I checked for you, curious (as I've not used VC++ for years). Apparently:

> These are now supported, but with this exception: For defaulted functions, the use of `=default` to request member-wise move constructors and move assignment operators is not supported

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input guys.  I did a little digging and found out the proper way to enable c++ 11 for dev.  You open tools --> complier options --> settings select the code generation tab and select ISO c++ 11.  Now it will compile properly.